# How do I return a value based on a text and number condition within Googlesheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to retrieve the values from **Hours** if column B contains "Prepared Meals" and then add the values from **Hours** to remaining hours? Ive tried vlookup, =IFS,  options and I cant seem to get this right. Please help if possible thank you!

[image]

Comment: I understand you want to SUM all the values in column E for rows where there the string "Prepared Meals" exists in column B and store that SUM in $K$5.  If so, you can create a hidden column (I'll call it X) with each row containing the formula =IF(B5="Prepared Meals",0,E5).  Then $K$5 contains = SUM(X:X)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet